How to dynamically add email recipients for WooCommerce new order emails?
Here’s a more precise version of your question for clarity and posting on forums like Stack Overflow:

Title:
"Duplicate new order emails when adding recipients dynamically using woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order hook"
Body:
I’m using the woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order filter to dynamically add an email address from an ACF field based on the order currency (EUR or GBP). While the additional email is correctly added, the issue is that duplicate emails are sent:

One email goes only to the dynamically added email.
Another email is sent to both the email set in WooCommerce settings and the dynamically added email.

Here’s my code:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'my_new_order_email_recipient', 10, 2 );

function my_new_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {

    $woocommerce_options = get_field( 'woocommerce', 'option' );

    if ( $woocommerce_options && isset( $woocommerce_options['order_emails'] ) ) {
        $order_emails = $woocommerce_options['order_emails'];

        $currency_emails = [
            'EUR' => $order_emails['euro_orders'] ?? '',
            'GBP' => $order_emails['sterling_orders'] ?? '',
        ];

        $current_currency = get_woocommerce_currency();

        if ( ! empty( $currency_emails[ $current_currency ] ) ) {
            $recipient = ', ' . $currency_emails[ $current_currency ];
        }
    }

    return $recipient;
}

The Problem:

Does the woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order filter fire multiple times?
Why is the $recipient variable causing duplicate emails instead of appending the new email address?

What I Need:
How can I ensure the dynamically added email address does not result in duplicate emails and works correctly alongside the WooCommerce default email settings?

You'll have to ask WooCommerce's support team about this; third-party plugin support is off topic here.
